# How to switch a Google account without resetting a phone?

Tags: gmail, google-account, lg-optimus-l3

On my Android LG Optimus Dynamic phone I originally entered an incorrect email when setting up the Google account to use. I want to switch emails now, but when I add the correct account and then try to delete the first account, it says it is required by some applications, and that I can only delete it by factory resetting the phone. However, that message does not come up when I try to delete the second account, and it removes fine.

How do I delete that original account so that I only have the new one left without factory resetting my phone? (I don't want to lose all of my apps and my contacts).

Comment: Which Android version is it? If you don't receive a working answer, then you can actually take backup of apps and contacts (irrespective of having root access (do you have it?)) and go ahead with factory reset.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall all Google applications on your phone, such as Google+, Youtube, Google Maps, Chrome, Voice Search etc. Then install the Google Installer app, and install all google applications. After installation, the Google App or Google Account Manager will prompt for account details. You can login with your required Google account. After that, the device will Sync the account to all other Google apps.

Comment: Oh sorry, my device is rooted. But since it is rooted, will all the accounts not sync?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention the version of Android you're using, but you did mention your device is rooted, so this app: [Erazzer](http://www.appbrain.com/app/erazzer/dsoft.Erazzer) may help:

> Please try FREE version of this program before buying it.
>
> This program will be very useful if you want to change the main Google account on your android device WITHOUT RESETTING it to the defaults preferences. Some features:
>
> - supported on Android 2.x
> - deleting Google accounts (2 methods)
> - accounts backup/restore
> - quick reboot/shutdown
> - widget for quick operations
>
> Warning! The function "reboot in recovery mode" can DELETE ALL DATA on some devices, it is disabled by defaults. Don't use it unless necessary or you do not know what it is

At this time, the webpage says: "This app is currently not active on Google Play". I don't know what that means, or if it will change.

Comment: @helper - I hesitate to approve the edit, but I don't want to reject it either. I don't disagree with the edits, but most (about 90%) of the edit is to make corrections to a section that's a word for word quote from another (linked) website/webpage. That webpage has changed (and is probably no longer maintained), but [an old archive of the page can be found here](http://web.archive.org/web/20130407133136/http://www.appbrain.com/app/erazzer/dsoft.Erazzer). I don't know it it's appropriate to make corrections to something that is quoted from offsite. Hopefully someone can provide some insight.

Answer (score 0):

Also on Samsung Galaxy A3 (2017) you can add another google account and remove the other one from the Cloud and accounts --> Accounts --> Google then 'Remove account' from top right menu.
It worked for me.